# Homebrew incompatible architecture error on M1 MacBook

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

I am getting below error while running `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` on my new M1 MacBook pro 16.

```
kevin@MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R kevin:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))).
Failed during: git init -q
kevin@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

This is my first time setting up development on macOS so please do let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Did you install Xcode command line tools.

Comment: yes, I have already installed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` with `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`and running `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`